# React Datetime Picker Component with Semantic UI React example

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I can't find a React Datetime component with proper documentation. I need a Datetime picker in a React project using Semantic UI React.

I tried https://github.com/react-component/calendar but can't get it running properly... It seems the options is very limited (which is odd btw..).

Can you provide a WORKING example of a datetime picker with these libs?

Comment: in react version of semantic ui datepicker is missing but there are separate NPM for date picker which will give same look as SUI https://github.com/arthurdenner/react-semantic-ui-datepickers

Answer (score 8):

I found https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker. Really simple to setup and use :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can use react-date picker for this

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

Comment: You certainly don't want to produce a bloated mix of both frameworks.